# jquery action div same class

Tags: jquery, class

for example

```
<div id="red">
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="two"></div>
<div class="three"></div>
</div>
<div id="blue">
<div id="sub" class="one"></div>
<div id="sub" class="two"></div>
<div id="sub" class="three"></div>
</div>
```

when I click .one show #sub .one, the same class name.
thanks

Comment: what?   dont reuse id, all ids should be unique

Comment: Don't use same `id` to multiple elements? And clarify you question

Comment: HTML fail! Don't reuse ids please. We have classes for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you shouldn't duplicate `id`s on a page, so I've restructured your HTML:

```
<div id="red">
    <div class="one"></div>
    <div class="two"></div>
    <div class="three"></div>
</div>
<div id="blue" class="sub">
    <div class="one"></div>
    <div class="two"></div>
    <div class="three"></div>
</div>
```

Then, you can do something like the following:

```
$('#red').on('click', 'div', function(ev){
    $('.sub div').hide();
    $('.sub .' + $(this).attr('class')).show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div id="red">
  <div class="one"></div>
  <div class="two"></div>
  <div class="three"></div>
</div>
<div id="blue">
  <div class="sub one"></div>
  <div class="sub two"></div>
  <div class="sub three"></div>
</div>

   $('.one').click(function(){
        $('.sub').hasClass('one').show();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="red">
  <div class="one"></div>
  <div class="two"></div>
  <div class="three"></div>
</div>
<div id="blue">
  <div id="one" class="sub"></div>
  <div id="two" class="sub"></div>
  <div id="three" class="sub"></div>
</div>

$().ready(function(){
  $('.sub').hide();
  $('#red>div').click(function(){
    $('#' + $(this).attr('class')).show();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this way, less code, more work:

jQuery:

```
$(function(){
  $('#red div').click(function(){//divs inside #red

    var takeClass = (this).attr('class');//takes clicked element's class

    //inside #blue div
    $('#blue .'+takeClass).show();//show's div which got clicked element's class
    // if clicked element's class is 'one', this will show '#blue .one'
  });
});
```

your html:

```
<div id="red">
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="two"></div>
<div class="three"></div>
</div>
<div id="blue">
<div id="sub" class="one"></div>
<div id="sub" class="two"></div>
<div id="sub" class="three"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**>> [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/eWmpJ/) <<**

I would advise to use toggle instead of show, like so:

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#blue div").hide();
    $("#red div").click(function() {
        var redClass = $(this).attr("class");
        $("#blue ." + redClass).toggle();
    });
});
```

**HTML structure:**

```
<div id="red">
    <div class="one">1</div>
    <div class="two">2</div>
    <div class="three">3</div>
</div>
<div id="blue" class="sub">
    <div class="one">1</div>
    <div class="two">2</div>
    <div class="three">3</div>
</div>​
```